# How to open native video player to play local contents in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, video-streaming

I have some **video file embedded with the project**, that to be opened in the native video player using Xamarin forms.

Note: Having in-app video player is limited here.

Any idea for this?

Comment: try these articles https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/

Comment: This article does'nt tells about playing a local content.

Comment: Did you check 5 articles on that link?

Comment: Where is video file ? `PCL` or `Xamarin.Android` `Assets` folder?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Its inside Raw folder of Xamarin.Android

Comment: @Sankarann, have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late, you could refer to [FormsNativeVideoPlayer](https://github.com/xamarin/customer-success-samples/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/FormsNativeVideoPlayer).
When you load your video file from `Raw`  folder, you just need to modify the [VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/customer-success-samples/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/FormsNativeVideoPlayer/Droid/VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.cs) code like this  :

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged (e);

    ...

    string uriPath = "android.resource://" + Forms.Context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.audio;
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse((uriPath));

    //Set the videoView with our uri, this could also be a local video on device
    videoView.SetVideoURI (uri);

    ...
 }
```